# Search through lists in Python to find matches?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have Python lists with various strings in them such  as:

```
List1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
List2 = ["b","d","e","f"]
List3 = []
List4 = ["d","f","g"]
```

I need to iterate through these lists, provided they are not blank, and finds items that are in all non-blank lists. In the above example, the exact matches list would  be ["d"], since that is the only item that appears in all non-blank lists. List3 is blank, so it would not matter that it is not in that list.

Comment: Does the order of the output list matter?

Comment: You "need a code"?

Comment: No it does not. As long as I can append each exact match to it.

Comment: Did you read [ask]?

Answer (score 4):

Here's some functional programming beauty:

```
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce

Lists = List1, List2, List3, List4

result = reduce(and_, map(set, filter(None, Lists)))
```

Comment: btw, `operator`-free version: `reduce(set.intersection, map(set, filter(None, Lists)))`

Comment: @timgeb, cool, it's gonna look even better this way. Also, less imports.

Comment: In addition, this saves manually converting all the lists to sets, only `Lists[0]` has to be a set. (I did not time whether this makes any difference.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for thing in list1: # iterate each item, you can check before hand if its not empty
      if len(list2) > 0: # if not empty
         if thing in list2: # in the list 
            # do the same thing for the other lists
```

something like that

Comment: `if len(list2) > 0: # if not empty`. `if list2:` would check that it's not an empty list (which is falsey).

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but something like the following should work:

```
intersection(set(l) for l in [List1, List2, List3, List4] if l)
```

It uses Python's built-in [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) datatype to do the intersection operation.

Comment: `intersection` is a method of `set`, not a standalone function.